android studio mainactivity package name from template or resource value
I am trying to do something like this. or templating like in html but I could not find good documentation, maybe I searched wrong.  I am also open for template suggestion.
Currently  what I have is this
package com.mydomain.myapp
 
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

Instead of this I would like to get the package name from strings or elsewhere where I keep the other constants.
 package "myStringValue"
     
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.AlertDialog

Does anyone know how to achieve this?  I have tried many methods but I am actually very unfamiliar to Java/Android Studio.  Many thanks
